# Bluetooth peripheral mode With HTC Desire 816

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have `HTC Desire 816`, and its Android version is `5.0.2`.
I want to try coding about `BLE peripheral` mode.
I use the following code:

```
BluetoothManager btManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = btManager.getAdapter();
btAdapter.isMultipleAdvertisementSupported();
```

It always returns `null` object.

Does HTC not support `BLE peripheral` mode?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Regarding BLE peripheral/advertising support:**

The HTC Desire 816 was released in February 2014 with Android 4.4. Months later, in November 2014, Google clarified that the only devices supporting BLE peripheral/advertising mode at this point were the Nexus 6 and Nexus 9 ([in this thread](https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=1570#c52)).

So I conclude, that the **Desire 816 does not support this mode**, although its Android API Level does. But with the lack of such a device I can not test this on my own.

**Regarding your code:**

I compared your code to my own implementation of BLE advertising. From my point of view this code should run successfully. Anyway I was confused, that `isMultipleAdvertisementSupported()` does not return a Boolean value. Looking into the [Android Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#isMultipleAdvertisementSupported()) I saw, that this method seems to only return true values. So, since it returns null for you, this would be another proof, that your device does not support BLE peripheral/advertising mode.

Hope this helps :)